# Flask app cannot run on google cloud run: service unavailable 503 error

Tags: python, authentication, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I created a web app with Flask that exposes the 8080 port and shows some html pages, and I deployed it with google cloud run.
This is the basic code.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=settings.session_lifetime_minutes)
    session.modified = True
    g.user = current_user

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('authentication.html')
```

However when I set up the ingress of the service available to everybody and I access the URL provided by Google (https://myproject.run.app) through the browser, I wait for 5/10 seconds and get 'Service unavailable'.
By inspecting the logs I see this error log:

```
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#malformed-response-or-connection-error"
```

However in the troubleshooting guide I found no useful information.

When I setup the ingress of the service available only to internal users and I try to use the curl suggested by google, I get something like:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>404 Page not found</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Page not found</h1>
<h2>The requested URL was not found on this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Can anyone help me to understand what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: ```Flask that exposes the 8080 port``` - How did you do this? What command do you have in your dockerfile to invoke your app?

Comment: I simply run the main, and in the main I have:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

Comment: I'm asking you how you run ```main``` from the docker file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment:

```
if name == "main":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

This is your probem `ssl_context="adhoc"`. The listener must use HTTP and not HTTPS.

```
if name == "main":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Suggestion: read the PORT value from the environment instead of hard coding.

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

Comment: Great it worked! However when I use my google auth2 authentication, Google does not allow me to login and gives me an error saying that the redirect_uri is not among the one I provided. Indeed Google allows me to add only redirect_uri with https in an app in production, but what can I do if the listener uses http?

Comment: @emanuele_f Use the Cloud Run service URL which supports HTTPS. You can find that in the Google Cloud Console. If you still have a problem, post a new question as more details will be required.

Comment: I tried but had no luck. This is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77971214/how-to-authenticate-through-openid-with-a-flask-web-app-deployed-on-google-cloud, I would be glad to receive your help! THanks :)