# How to authenticate through openID with a flask web app deployed on google cloud run?

Tags: http, flask, google-cloud-platform, https, google-cloud-run

I have a Flask app deployed on google run. The login endpoint makes the user login through google openID authentication.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    client = WebApplicationClient(google_client_id)
    google_provider_config = requests.get('https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration').json()
    authorization_endpoint = google_provider_config["authorization_endpoint"]
    request_uri = client.prepare_request_uri(authorization_endpoint, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=["openid", "email", "profile"])
    request_uri = authenticator.get_request_uri(request.base_url + "/callback")
    return redirect(request_uri)

@app.route("/login/callback")
def callback():
    return redirect('/form')

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=settings.host, port=settings.port)
```

Since Google itself handles https requests, I know that Flask receives only http requests. However when I try to login, I get the error redirect_uri mismatch: http://my-project.run.app/login/callback.
Indeed I could insert only http uris (https://my-project.run.app/login/callback for example) among the authorized redirect uris in my OpenID credentials, since my app is in production. Therefore I should probably make flask use https instead of http, even though it is listening to http requests.

Is this correct? How can I do this in code?
Thank you!

Comment: Edit your post with error message details. For Google Cloud Run and many other services, Google provides the GFE (Google Front End). That service provides the HTTPS URL and SSL certificate. When you enter the Redirect URI in the Cloud Console Client ID page, always use the `https` version of the Cloud Run URL. Your problem might also be due to the proxy settings and Flask not detecting `https`. Review  this document: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/deploying/proxy_fix/

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23504684/8016720) from Martijn might also help you.